# Parallel task execution breaks the order when parallel ,normal tasks mixed together

Tags: gradle, groovy, parallel-processing

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task taskA <<{
    println 'task A'
}

task taskB (type:P){
    namee='B'
}

task taskC (type:P){
    namee='C'
}

@ParallelizableTask
class P extends DefaultTask {
    String namee

    @TaskAction
    def broccoliBuild() {
        println "Task "+namee
    }
}

task taskBC (dependsOn:['taskB','taskC'])<<{
    println 'BC'
}
taskBC.mustRunAfter taskA

task taskD <<{
    println'task D'
}
taskD.mustRunAfter taskBC

task taskE (type:Qtask){
    nname='E'
}

task taskF (type:Qtask){
    nname='F'
}

@ParallelizableTask
class Qtask extends DefaultTask {
    String nname

    @TaskAction
    def broccoliBuild() {
        println "Task "+nname
    }
}

task taskEF (dependsOn:['taskE','taskF'])<<{
    println 'task EF'
}
taskEF.mustRunAfter taskD

task main(dependsOn: ['taskA','taskBC','taskD','taskEF'])<<{
    println 'Build Completed'
}
```

When i execute the main task in parallel mode:

> gradle main --parallel -Dorg.gradle.parallel.intra=true

`taskEF` executes along with `taskBC` (Both of them is parallel tasks) which violates the flow i have mentioned. 
`taskD` must be executed before `taskEF` (I have used mustRunAfter ) .

Please can any one help me out of this. (Used Gradle 2.12)

Comment: Can you please provide your Gradle output? I run the script locally many times and `taskD` was always executed before `taskEF`.

Answer (score 0):

After the contents of your `build.gradle` file and adding the `wrapper` task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'  
}
```

I ran the following command: `gradlew wrapper` and then checked the version, which shows I am properly running the expected **Gradle 2.12** version

```
E:\Data\Test>gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-03-14 08:32:03 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b29fbb64ad6b068cb3f05f7e40dc670472129bc0

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Then, running the command you provided, here is the results:

```
E:\Data\Test>gradlew main --parallel -Dorg.gradle.parallel.intra=true

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:taskA
task A
:taskB
:taskC
:taskE
:taskF
Task C
Task B
Task F
Task E
:taskBC
BC
:taskD
task D
:taskEF
task EF
:main
Build Completed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.609 secs
```

So, with `Gradle 2.12` the output does run as you expect and the `taskEF` correctly runs after `taskBC`.

It appears that you are either not running the proper version of Gradle you intend or the version of the `build.gradle` you are actually running against is different than the one you provided here.

As a side note: I would suggest always run Gradle using the wrapper task as I have shown, which makes updating or choosing a specific Gradle version a snap.